# Is there a purely constructive presentation of the HK integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, foundations, constructive-mathematics

Treating the Riemann integral in a constructive setting is easy and straightforward. Treating the closely related but much more powerful [Henstock-Kurzweil integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral) constructively is *almost* easy, except for the dependence on Cousin's lemma where every proof seems to involve the excluded middle.

In a constructive (or slightly stronger intuitionistic) setting, is there a way to:

- define the HK integral
- prove that the HK integral is unique
- define another notion of integrability which constructively implies HK-integrability and is classically equivalent to Lebesgue integrability
- and prove that every derivative, even if discontinuous, is HK-integrable?

One approach would be restricting the choice of gauge to Baire functions, since under fairly general assumptions the gauge can be chosen to be Baire 2. This would require proving Cousin's lemma only for Baire functions, which looks more promising than proving the full Cousin’s lemma constructively.

I have seen a paper on [the reverse mathematics of Cousin’s lemma](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.13060v1), but that is not in a constructive setting.

Comment: [Cross-posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4400212/is-there-a-constructive-presentation-of-the-henstock-kurzweil-integral)

Comment: I edited this to make it easier to read, to remove the references to set theory (since most formal systems for constructive math are not based on set theory), and to remove the requirement of proving Bolzano-Weierstrass and Heine-Borel (which is not a clear criterion, since the theorems could be stated in different ways). The criteria here for proving statements about the HK integral constructively are substantial enough that further requirements don’t seem necessary. However, feel free to edit further or to revert if you don’t like this version.

Comment: @MattF. As it turns out, the answer to the HK integral being well-defined is positive (the full Cousin's lemma is provable) when we can prove things like the BW and HB theorems (the axiom I added in my answer was open induction). I suspect that it might be doable with just the fan theorem but don't have a proof yet. I ended up just adding "(or slightly stronger intuitionistic)" for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few months later, I ended up proving it in constructive analysis with open induction and no countable choice. Since the open induction principle follows from Brouwer's bar theorem (it in turn implies the fan theorem so adding it as an axiom is necessary), it is available in the internal language of any sheaf topos over a locally countably compact topological space, including sheaves over any manifold with corners, which is good enough for every application I care about.

This is a proof from a draft of some notes I've been working on, with rudimentary use of Coq to check that the proof isn't completely wrong.

So let's state open induction:

An **open** subset $S$ of a closed real interval $[a,b]$ is said to be **inductive** if it satisfies that $[a,r) \subset S$ implies $[a,r] \subset S$. The **open induction principle** states that any inductive subset $S$ of $[a,b]$ must be the entire set.

Now to the theorem and proof.

(Cousin's theorem) For any gauge $\delta : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}+$, there exists a $\delta$-fine tagged partition of $[a,b]$.

Proof:

Let $S$ be the set of points $r$ such that there exists a $\delta$-fine tagged partition on $[a,s]$ of length n for some $s \geq r$.
The set $S$ is clearly open, since it is downwards closed and any point in it is included in the open ray $ [a,b] \cap [a,t_n + \delta(t_n) ) \subset S$ for any associated partition.

Furthermore, it is inductive. For any $r$, suppose $[a,r) \subset S$. By that assumption (and using that either $r > a + \tfrac{2}{3}\delta(a)$ or $r \in [a, a + \delta(a)) \subset S$ to handle edge cases) we have a partition of length $n$ with $x_n \geq r - \tfrac{1}{2} \mathrm{min}(\delta(a), \delta(r)) > a$.

Then, setting $\Delta_n = t_n + \delta(t_n) - x_n > 0$, then either $x_n > b - \Delta_n$ or $x_n < b $. In the first case $b < t_n + \delta(t_n)$, so we can just replace $x_n$ with $b$ and get a partition of $[a,b]$ that includes $r$. If $x_n < b$, then we can make a partition of length $n+1$, since either we have $r < x_n + \delta(x_n)$ in which case we can set $t_{n+1} = x_n$ or we have $r > x_n$ in which case we can set $t_{n+1} = r$. In both cases, we can set $x_{n+1} = \mathrm{min}(b, t_{n+1} + \delta(t_{n+1})) > x_n$. So $[a,r] \subset S$ in all cases, and $S$ is inductive.

By open induction, $S = [a,b]$.

I'm planning to host the notes somewhere and add the proof to the wikipedia article on Cousin's lemma once I'm done with minor edits.

Comment: So what's the story about the extent to which Denjoy's original definition is constructive?

Comment: @TimothyChow Right, that is for a different meaning of the word constructive. The meaning of the word intended for this question is a bit more specific and means working without the law of the excluded middle, typically because you want the proof to still work in specific sheaf models with weaker internal logics than ZF.

Comment: Another minor note: the $t_{n+1} = max(r,x_n)$ is a shorthand for splitting on $x_n < r$ or $r < x_n + \delta(x_n)$. No hidden LLPO is used.

Comment: Ended up making an edit to make the split explicit in the proof, even if I use min/max for terseness.

Comment: The maximum function $\max  : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is constructive, no “shorthand” is needed.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of mathematical text.

Comment: It is constructive, but afaik using that it is equal to one of its arguments is LLPO. I will format the math here as well now that I am no longer editing the proof.

Comment: Edited the answer with a copypaste of the final version of the proof in my notes.

Comment: @AndrejBauer The main reason why I care about this is because in this proof I don't want to have to assume that the gauge respects anything more than definitional equality. So AFAIK, for setoids it can be a prefunction and the proof should still work.

Comment: Thanks for writing up the proof. I wonder, do we even need for the gauge to be a map? Could it be a relation and things still work out?

Comment: I think the gauge is really a choice of entourage, and that the right generalization would be locally compact uniform spaces, but I'd have to investigate that more closely.

Comment: Additional notes: the lemma above can be improved to hold for what I am currently calling fuzzy partitions, where you have a partition of unity by absolutely continuous nonnegative functions $h_i$, with disjoint sets where $h_i(r) > \varepsilon > 0$, and tags in that set, with $h_i$ having support only within $\delta(t_i)$ of $t_i$. That is a nicer generalization to work with without LLPO imho, and extending that to higher dimensions should makes it feasible to define fuzzified Pfeffer-type integrals uniquely.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, the following paper deals with the HK-integral and constructive math, see [2] below for details.

Taschner R., *The swap of integral and limit in constructive mathematics*.

Secondly, the general HK integral may be (too) difficult to salvage, as the associated versions of Cousin's lemma (even the restrictions you mention) seem fundamentally non-constructive.

Thirdly, the HK integral restricted to absolutely integrable functions is the Lebesgue integral (on suitable domains).  Hence, there should be a constructive treatment of this restriction.  In particular, in the case of bounded functions, one can replace the use of Cousin's lemma by Vitali's covering theorem (see Section 3.5 in [1]), where the latter is 'more constructive' than the former.  Also, since constructive measure theory exists, there is a 'constructive way around' Vitali's covering theorem, central as the latter is to Lebesgue measure theory (see again [1]).

References

[1] Dag Normann and Sam Sanders, the logical and computational properties of the Vitali covering theorem, arxiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.02756

[2] Taschner R., *The swap of integral and limit in constructive mathematics*, Math. Log. Quart. 56, No. 5, 533 – 540 (2010) / DOI 10.1002/malq.200910107